# Use a column of arrays as a condition in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I want to use a column of arrays as a condition in postgres. The condition is applied on a column composed of text value.

This is the column made out of arrays (after be transformed with string_to_array.

[image]

And this is the tax_role column.

[image]

I'tried a mix of `ANY` and `IN` but I get this error message.

Here's my script :

```
select
*
from tax_role
where tax_role_2021.address_num IN ANY
      (SELECT string_to_array(corporate_data.address_num, '-') FROM corporate_data 
       where lower(corporate_data.name) LIKE '%some_name%'); -- this is the query that return the arrays
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the misuse of the `IN` and `ANY` clauses together.

In PostgreSQL, when you're comparing against an array, you can use the `ANY` keyword, but it's not used in conjunction with `IN`. Instead, you can use it like this:

Try this modified script:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tax_role
WHERE tax_role_2021.address_num = ANY
      (SELECT string_to_array(corporate_data.address_num, '-') 
       FROM corporate_data 
       WHERE lower(corporate_data.name) LIKE '%some_name%');
```

This script will compare each `address_num` in `tax_role_2021` against the arrays returned by the subquery. If there's a match, the row from `tax_role` will be included in the result set.

Comment: I realized I did'nt give enough details. I edited my question. Sorry for that. It seems I can't compare because they are not the same type of value, but I was wondering if there was a way to compare.

Comment: The error you're encountering is due to the misuse of the IN and ANY clauses together. Have you tried removing the "IN" yet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a little unclear when considering the use of IN or ANY. It depends on your use case.

If you want to check that an address number is in a specific set you should use the `IN` keyword, or if you want to match with any of its occurrences, you should opt for the `ANY` keyword. But do not use both at the same time.

Your subquery to convert a string to an array seems perfect so there is no issue in that.

I believe that in your case, the keyword `IN` will be used, try modifying Joaquin's query with IN keyword. It should work then.